# how to take select query output of one coloumn in another column

Tags: sql

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name='AUTHUAT' then 'pramod' else 'ladkat' end from v$database;
```

output:

name
pramod

i Want output as :

```
__name____|_other name____
pramod    |     ladkat
```

Comment: Add sample table data (like 10 rows), and it's expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're maybe looking for conditional aggregation ?

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN name='AUTHUAT' then 'pramod' else 'ladkat' end) as name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name='AUTHUAT' then 'pramod' else 'ladkat' end) as other_name
from v$database;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the expected result you have to use the following query and you can avoid else part in the case if you want to display data in matched condition only. You can also set NULL or '' in else to display NULL or Blank value in case of mismatch:

```
SELECT   
    CASE WHEN name='AUTHUAT' THEN 'pramod' ELSE 'ladkat' END name, 
    CASE WHEN name='AUTHUAT' THEN 'ladkat' ELSE 'pramod' END other_name
FROM v$database;
```